# Access Cookies with Fluid (Typo3)

Tags: cookies, typo3, fluid

I am looking for a way to access cookie-values in Fluid. There are ways to do it with extensions but if possible I was hoping for a way to do it in fluid...

Comment: As far as I remember there's no such VH. There is one in VHS, but you need to check if it meets your requirements. If you won't find any it's rather easy to write custom VH, just need to remember about caching. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs

Comment: p.s. of course you can use TS for conditional cookies.

Comment: Here is an example for TypoScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563575/2819581 
You can access TypoScript objects in Fluid with this ViewHelper https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in fluid directly. There are tons of ways how you can achieve it:

- Using a custom dataprocessor
- Use a custom viewhelper
- Use the `<f:cObject` ViewHelper and TS (as described above)
- Use an existing extension like vhs if this does the job as well.

---

However, please always don't forget the caching as otherwise TYPO3 will just cache the 1st hit of the page and returns the output to everyone else as well!